# A sphere is a surface.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

How to show a sphere is a surface.

$x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$

Note that I need to find a homeopmhism $\phi : U \to S$ for $U$ in $\Bbb R^2$ and $S$ in $\Bbb R^3$

Let $U=[0,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]$ 
Then I defined a surface patch $\phi (u,v)= (R\sin u \cos u, R\sin v \sin u, R\cos v)$

After there, what do I need to do in order to show that a sphere is a surface?

Comment: This is not possible. No subset of the plane is homeomorphic to the sphere.

Comment: You should review your definition of what a surface is. There is not subset of the plane homeomorphic to the sphere. Are you sure you're not looking for coordinate charts?

Comment: Hmm.. Can someone show the correct answer? Please. I dont want to learn false.

Comment: Suppose that $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open an connected and you remove $1$ point from $U$. Then $U$ is no longer simply connected. But, if you remove $1$ point from $S^2$, it is still simply connected.

Comment: @Tom how is showing  that $R^{2}$ isnt homomorphic to $s^{2}$ aplly that $S^{2}$ is a manifold?

Comment: @EliElizirov I was justifying the previous comments that an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: My idea is mistake, i see. But I dont know how to show that this is a surface. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map every open set $U$ in your chart to an open subset $V$ in the sphere (defihomorphizem from $U$ to $V$ )
.
The basic map $\phi(t,s)=(t,s,\sqrt{1-t^2-s^2}$) this will cover half of the sphere without the "Equator" to cover the all sphere you need another 5 charts, 6 charts in total

Comment: Okay, if I show these six charts, the union of these 6 charts is an atlas for the sphere. Thus, the sphere is a surface. Is this right?

Comment: @B11b Yes, it is. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is: if $f: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ is given by $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$, we have that $\nabla f(x,y,z) = 2(x,y,z)$. The gradient is the null vector only if $(x,y,z) = \bf 0$. But ${\bf 0} \not\in f^{-1}(\{R^2\})$, so $R^2$ is a regular value of $f$ and then:$$f^{-1}(\{R^2\}) = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \ / \ x^2+y^2+z^2 = R^2\}$$ is a surface.